# Website - Change image depending on mouse position (2 zones)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following situation quite simple (1 page, 3 zones : left - center - right ) :

HTML :

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="answer-on-the-right-or-left">
        Left zone
    </div>

    <div class="picture-in-the-middle">
        <img src="@Url.Content("/content/images/qres/faceblackandwhite.png")"/>
    </div>

    <div class="answer-on-the-right-or-left">
        Right zone
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.page { width: 800px; height: 500px; }

.answer-on-the-right-or-left { float: left; width : 300px; height: 500px; }

.picture-in-the-middle { float: left; width : 150px; height: 500px; }
```

I would like to do the following thing :

- When the mouse is on the left zone, the picture in the middle changes to : `"/content/images/qres/facecolorleft.png"`
- When the mouse is on the right zone : `"/content/images/qres/facecolorright.png"`
- Everywhere else, the image stays : `"/content/images/qres/faceblackandwhite.png"`

I know how to do a mouseover on a picture with javascript, but i cannot find the solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an id to each zone:

```
<div class="answer-on-the-right-or-left" id="leftZone">Left Zone</div>
<div class="answer-on-the-right-or-left" id="rightZone">Right Zone</div>
```

and bind hover

```
$('.answer-on-the-right-or-left').hover(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var img = $('.picture-in-the-middle img');

   if(id == 'leftZone') img.attr('src', '/content/images/qres/facecolorleft.png');
   else if(id == 'rightZone') img.attr('src', '/content/images/qres/facecolorright.png');

}, function() {
   $('.picture-in-the-middle img').attr('src', '/content/images/qres/faceblackandwhite.png');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i am trying it. I forgot to ask if we could preload those images (otherwise the user will have to wait for the image to change).

Comment: It works very well thank you ! (just a little delay in loading the images, if you know a way to integrate a preload ...)